# Fingerprint login option sometimes not available on login screen

Tags: login, thinkpad, fingerprint-reader

I have a strange problem on my Ubuntu 22.04 installation. The fingerprint login sometimes does not work. When it does not work I don't see the **`(or place finger on reader)`** message under password box.

Is this a feature or a bug? If it is a feature, on what basis does it decide whether to allow fingerprint login or not? If it is a bug, is there a resolution or workaround?

I have seen other threads related to fingerprint login issues, but there the problem is not intermittent like mine.

Hardware: Lenovo L15 Gen3 (AMD)
OS: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Following this thread I found I needed to update my /etc/pam.d/gdm-fingerprint as below.  The last line was pointing to pam_fprintd.so, but as per thread https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/171136 I found pam_deny.so was what is needed.

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth    requisite       pam_nologin.so
auth    required        pam_succeed_if.so user != root quiet_success
auth    required        pam_fprintd.so
auth    optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so
@include common-account
# SELinux needs to be the first session rule. This ensures that any 
# lingering context has been cleared. Without this it is possible 
# that a module could execute code in the wrong domain.
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so close
session required        pam_loginuid.so
# SELinux needs to intervene at login time to ensure that the process
# starts in the proper default security context. Only sessions which are
# intended to run in the user's context should be run after this.
# pam_selinux.so changes the SELinux context of the used TTY and configures
# SELinux in order to transition to the user context with the next execve()
# call.
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so open
session optional        pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session required        pam_limits.so
session required        pam_env.so readenv=1
session required        pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
@include common-session
session optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
# causes issue with fingerprint, change to pam_deny.so
# and it works every time
#password required       pam_fprintd.so
password required       pam_deny.so
```